# Cascade deletion does not trigger PostRemove

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

My entities are as follows:

- a Portfolio has many Series [OneToMany-ManyToOne]
- a Serie has many Assets [OneToMany-ManyToOne]
- a Serie can have an Asset (as a thumbnail) [OneToOne]

I also used the *cascade={"remove"}* property in order to remove the Series and Assets if the corresponding Portfolio has been deleted.

**Serie**

```
/**
 * Serie
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="serie")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Serie
{
    /**
     * @var \Portfolio
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Portfolio", inversedBy="series")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="portfolio", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $portfolio;
    /**
     * @var \Image
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="preview", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     * })
     */
    private $preview;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Asset", mappedBy="serie", cascade={"remove"})
     **/
    private $assets;

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove
     */
    public function removeDirectory(){ 
        rmdir(...);
    }
```

**Asset**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="asset")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Asset
{
    /**
     * @var \Serie
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Serie", inversedBy="assets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="serie", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    protected $serie;

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeFile()
    {
        unlink($this->filename);
    }
```

I put the *cascade={"remove"}* property in Asset's side of the relationship [because the other way around would result in a foreign key constraint error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441940/doctrine-cascade-removing-fails-with-onetomany-and-onetoone/31442089#31442089)

The postRemove method in Serie is called but not the one in Asset. Am I doing something wrong, is there a way to fix it?

Comment: So you're sure the removal actually occurs, you're just not getting the lifecycle-callback on the entity? If you add another kind like `PrePersist`, does that work?

Comment: @Darien PrePersist does occur when I'm creating entities. However, I can't really make it happens in the exact same conditions (which means, when the entities are removed by cascade of another entity also removed by cascade of another entity).I'm sure the removing happens as there isn't any entities in the Asset table anymore.

Comment: So far I can't seem to reproduce the problem with unit-tests. You're sure that Portfolio cascade-removes to Series which cascade-removes to Asset, and the only problem is that the callback isn't being hit? The cascading is occurring in Doctrine, and not through the database's row-level "on delete cascade" mechanisms?

Comment: @Darien Yes I'm sure it's cascading, here's why: when creating a Serie for a Portfolio, a `PrePersist` function on Serie creates a directory. This directory is then deleted with the `PostRemove` on Serie, ergo after every assets are deleted. However, when I'm deleting a Portfolio, the Assets are deleted in the database (no entries in this table anymore, and they used to be there), the whole process fails with Symfony indicating that the directory is NOT empty: the files linked to the Asset were not removed, and I did not have any error messages for it... It was not called.

Comment: I also found this ... It might explain why? : http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2524

Comment: I have the same problem, any solutions yet?